# calculating page rendering time in jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, rendering

how can we find rendering time from using values such as Latency, Connect time, Elapsed Time, Idle Time available to us in jtl file generated at end of test?

Is the below approach correct?

Rendering Time = Elapsed Time - Connect Time - Latency

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This way (excluding network transport metrics) you will be able to get **server response time**, however as per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. **Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).**

So JMeter will not actually load DOM, execute scripts, and display the generated page, it just sends a request, receives "plain" response and measures time in-between.

If you need to measure page rendering page while your application is under the load I would recommend going for [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium browser automation framework](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). This way you will be able to measure real user experience and you will have a possibility to use [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) to get some extra information regarding page loading events and their duration.

Comment: Thanks for guidance!